# calling mongoose schema method while creating the object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I made a schema method that converts plain passwords into a secure password. But when I try to use it while creating an object of a specified model, but it gives an error "Undefined schema method".

controller code

```
const Admin=require("path of admin schema");

const admin=new Admin({
                encryptPassword:Admin.encryptPassword(req.body.password)
            });
```

Admin model code

```
adminSchema.methods.securePassword=function(plainPassword)
  {
      if(!plainPassword)
      {
          return ""
      }
      try {
          return crypto.createHmac('sha256', "hello")
          .update(plainPassword)
          .digest('hex');
          
      } catch (error) {
          console.log(error)
          return ""
      }
  }
```

I want to use this method while creating any new admin. method works fine with any existing admin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make that method into a static method to be able to access it through the class and not the instance

Resource: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/methods-statics.html

```
adminSchema.statics.securePassword=function(plainPassword) {
  if(!plainPassword) {
      return ""
  }
  try {
      return crypto.createHmac('sha256', "hello")
      .update(plainPassword)
      .digest('hex');
      
  } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
      return ""
  }
}
```

Now you will be able to access it as

```
 const safePassword = Admin.securePassword(req.body.password)
```